# Calendar plugin that can be used as a date picker as well as date range picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to search for a calendar plugin(not date picker) that is responsive and can be used to select a single date or multiple dates within a given range( 7 days to be exact). Also i need to be able to manipulate the calendar plugin such that it only shows three months backward from the current system date beyond which date selection will not be allowed.

All suggestions are welcome and thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this date range picker and I think this is what you need. Most of the times I prefer this one. It also has predefined ranges e.g select last 7 days etc.

http://www.daterangepicker.com/